# Flask debug=True exploitation

Tags: web-application, webserver, python

It's a well known fact that Flask's `debug=True` option can lead to remote code execution via werkzeug debugger capabilities and even several [resources were hacked](https://labs.detectify.com/2015/10/02/how-patreon-got-hacked-publicly-exposed-werkzeug-debugger/). I decided to look into it and it turned out that the technique doesn't work if the app is being run by a forking application server like uwsgi or gunicorn. So the questions are:

1. Is there an opportunity to exploit Flask application with `debug=True` enabled even if it's being run by a forking application server (gunicorn, uwsgi)? I can't believe that all this hacked resources used built-in Flask's web server in production.
2. Did all that hacked sites run Flask app directly without using "standard" approach like nginx + gunicorn/uwsgi + Flask?

Comment: The latest flask has a debugger PIN which prevents exploitation

Comment: Sure, I'm aware of it. But let's assume it's disabled or older version of werkzeug is used.

Comment: The Werkzeug debugger is WSGI middleware, so you can use it with any app server. You may have to jump through a couple of hoops to enable it (not sure, not done it myself). Also, I wouldn't be overly surprised if some sites were using the built-in dev server in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we enable the debugger with this code:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

That only enables the debugger with the built-in dev server. To use the Werkzeug debugger with another WSGI server, we have to explicitly include the middleware:

```
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication 
from waitress import serve
app = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True, pin_security=False)
serve(app, listen='*:8080')
```

When you do this, with `evalex` and `pin_security` options as above, the app is trivially vulnerable to remote compromise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested it and it really works with Waitress, however it doesn't work with gunicorn and uwsgi.

Comment: @CaptainRR - Can you edit your question to include the exact config you're using

Comment: Please find the whole test application at https://www.sendspace.com/file/hwvuk6 Just edit the Dockerfile for different configurations